# Is it possible to authenticate a user through a plugin AND does not return that user in user searches?

Tags: authentication, plone

I'm talking about interaction between IUserEnumerationPlugin and IAuthenticationPlugin.

Plone has a strange behaviour about the possibility to flag (activate) the IAuthenticationPlugin without flagging IUserEnumerationPlugin too.

You can add in ZMI -> Plone -> acl_users a simple "ZODB user manager"; add a dummy user in it; and activate only the Authentication flag.

You will get that the user authenticate correctly at login (welcome message is printed as well as userid in place of login tab) but the authentication cookie seems that didn't being set: browsing any other page brings you back to anonymous state.

Dunno if it is a bug, but I need to authenticate users without let them show in sharing page or in usergroup-userprefs searches as they are managed elsewhere.